# Creating an instance in addOnLoad method of dojo doesn't have global scope

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've a Utils class in JavaScript. Below is the source code of that JavaScript.

```
function UtilityMethod(){
     this.testMethod=function(){
        alert("Test method is called");
    }
}
```

Above code is included in Utils.js file.Now I need to create an instance of UtilityMethod in my HTML File. I've referenced Utils.js in my HTML file. Below is my HTML Code.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Utils.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
            var Utils = new UtilityMethod();
        });
    </script>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Utils.testMethod()">TestMethodCall</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

But when I click on the HyperLink, it is giving me the error Utils is not defined. But even though I'm clicking on the link after page load, why is it still giving the error?
I need to include the instance creation in dojo.addOnLoad() method. Can you please suggest if there are other easy alternatives to this?

I know that we can do this using dojo.connect(), but is there another approach to do this. If we are using dojo.connect, we have to make changes to lot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Utils is created in a function; it won't be available outside the function. A nice explanation of this scoping behavior can be found [here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes). To make this work, you'll need to tell the browser that Utils is a global variable:

```
window.Utils = new UtilityMethod();
```

Now, Utils is set on the window object thus making it accessible anywhere (A nice feat of the window object is that its properties are available without the `window.` prepended, so you can still use `Utils.testMethod` as normal)